# Python - Beautifulsoup - Nonetype

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Morning folks.

I am scraping some data from a letting site using Beautifulsoup and Requests.

I am managing to get the data as needed but keep getting an error when I add .text any help would be appreciated, Code below and error further down.  The ANC code does return correctly just with the error

```
for item in house_link_list:
    url = item
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

    result = soup.find_all('table', class_="tableproperty")

    for item in result:
        advert = item.find('td', attrs={'data-title': 'Advert'})
        post_code = item.find('td', attrs={'data-title': 'Post code'})
        house_area = item.find('td', attrs={'data-title': 'Area'})
        landlord = item.find('td', attrs={'data-title': 'Landlord'})
        property_type = item.find('td', attrs={'data-title': 'Property type'})
        floor_level = item.find('td', attrs={'data-title': 'Floor level'})
        opening_data = item.find('td', attrs={'data-title': 'Opening date'})
        closing_date = item.find('td', attrs={'data-title': 'Closing date'})
        bedrooms = item.find('td', attrs={'data-title': 'Bedrooms'})
        heating_type = item.find('td', attrs={'data-title': 'Heating type'})
        double_glazed = item.find('td', attrs={'data-title': 'Double glazed'})
        garden = item.find('td', attrs={'data-title': 'Garden'})
        pets = item.find('td', attrs={'data-title': 'Pet allowed'})
        rent = item.find('td', attrs={'data-title': 'Rent'})

        print(advert.text)
        print(post_code)
        print(house_area)
        print(landlord)
        print(property_type)
        print(floor_level)
        print(opening_data)
        print(closing_date)
        print(bedrooms)
        print(heating_type)
        print(double_glazed)
        print(garden)
        print(pets)
        print(rent)
```

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\natha\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\main.py", line 87, in <module>
    get_details()
  File "C:\Users\natha\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\main.py", line 67, in get_details
    print(advert.text)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
ANC302774
<td data-title="Post code">DD9 6BE</td>
<td data-title="Area">BRECHIN NORTH AREA</td>
<td data-title="Landlord">Angus Council</td>
<td data-title="Property type">Flat</td>
<td data-title="Floor level">Ground floor</td>
<td data-title="Opening date">29/10/2021</td>
<td data-title="Closing date">05/11/2021</td>
<td data-title="Bedrooms">1</td>
None
None
None
None
None
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the docs say [beautifulsoup documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#miscellaneous):

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'foo' - This usually happens because you called find() and then tried to access the .foo attribute of the result. But in your case, find() didn’t find anything, so it returned None, instead of returning a tag or a string. You need to figure out why your find() call isn’t returning anything.

#### How to check?

```
print(advert.text if advert else 'no advert' )
```

or

```
advert = item.find('td', attrs={'data-title': 'Advert'}) if item.find('td', attrs={'data-title': 'Advert'}) else None
```